# install cx_Oracle on ubuntu 14.04 for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, cx-oracle

I've installed cx_Oracle on my ubuntu (kubuntu) 14.04 by typing

```
sudo pip3 install cx_Oracle
```

I've also installed instantclient12.1.

When running with python3 a .py script, I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

At the 'import' line.

Any suggestions?

**SOLVED:** for some reasons, by typing python3 on terminal, python3.5 is started, while cx_Oracle packages were installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.4 folder. Hence, by running 3.4 on terminal, I'm now able to import cx_Oracle module.

Comment: Were there any error messages when you ran pip install? Did you already have the 12.1 instant client *INCLUDING* the development package?